# Pan inside window using d3-drag/d3-zoom ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

My "drag to pan" functionality suddenly stopped working. I'm getting this error in node_modules/d3-zoom/src/zoom:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ctrlKey')
```

It seems like this functions has "props" undefined when I try to pan in the window.

```
function defaultFilter(event) {
  return (!event.ctrlKey || event.type === 'wheel') && !event.button;
}
```

My versions of d3:

```
    "d3": "^5.15.0",
    "d3-selection": "^1.3.0",
    "d3-drag": "^1.2.5",
```

The file I'm working in is quite large, so I'm just going to paste some code related to the functionality that is not working as intended.

My imports in the file looks like this:

```
import { event } from "d3";
import { drag } from "d3-drag";
import { select } from "d3-selection";
import { zoom, zoomTransform } from "d3-zoom";
```

Adding the d3 functionality here in the Class constructor:

```
    // Get window root to use with d3
    const windowRoot = select(window.document.body);

    // Set svg background
    this.svg = windowRoot.select(`#${id}`).append("svg");

    // Set canvas
    const canvas = windowRoot.select(`#${id}`).append("canvas");
    this.canvas = {
      elD3: canvas,
      dom: canvas.node(),
      ctx: canvas.node().getContext("2d"),
      width: null,
      height: null,
      ratio: null,
      zoom: zoom(),
      cluster: new Cluster({
        radius: 40,
        maxZoom: this.options.maxZoom,
        log: this.options.log,
      }),
    };

    // Load data
    this.canvas.cluster.load(this.tags);

    // Add d3 events to the canvas
    this.canvas.elD3.call(
      drag()
        .container(this.canvas.dom)
        .subject(() => this._dragSubject())
        .on("start", () => this._onDragStart())
        .on("start.render", () => this.render())
    );

    // Update window and render
    this.updateWindow();
```

Functions that are used in the call()

```
// Private methods
  _dragSubject() {
    const { poiRadius } = this.options;
    const { transform, ratio, tags, selectedTag } = this;
    const x = transform.invertX(event.x);
    const y = transform.invertY(event.y);
    const r = poiRadius / transform.k;
    const node = findNode(tags, x, y, ratio, r);
    if (selectedTag) selectedTag.active = false;
    this.selectedTag = node;
    dispatchEvent(this.document, EVENTS.SELECT_TAG, { tag: node });
    if (!node) this.render();
    return node;
  }

  _onDragStart() {
    const { tags } = this;
    tags.splice(tags.indexOf(event.subject), 1);
    event.subject.active = true;
    tags.push(event.subject);
  }
```

```
  render() {
    const { tags, canvas } = this;
    canvas.cluster.load(tags);
    this.clear();
    this._renderBackground();
    this._renderTags();
  }
```

```
/**
   * Resize view.
   */
  updateWindow() {
    const { container, background, svg, canvas } = this;
    const { elD3, zoom } = canvas;
    // Update width and height
    container.width = container.dom.offsetWidth;
    container.height = container.dom.offsetHeight;
    const ratio = getRatio(
      container.width,
      container.height,
      background.width,
      background.height
    );
    elD3.attr("width", background.width * ratio);
    elD3.attr("height", background.height * ratio);
    elD3.style("position", "absolute");
    svg.attr("width", background.width * ratio);
    svg.attr("height", background.height * ratio);
    // Update canvas
    canvas.width = elD3.node().width;
    canvas.height = elD3.node().height;
    canvas.ratio = ratio;
    // Update canvas events
    zoom
      .translateExtent([
        [0, 0],
        [canvas.width, canvas.height],
      ])
      .extent([
        [0, 0],
        [canvas.width, canvas.height],
      ]);
    // Render
    this.render();
  }
```

#### What I think the issue is

Something with how the d3 library is set up for panning, the event prop is not set properly. So maybe something how the libraries are used is incorrect. I hope someone has any ideas. Thanks.